# Why is the default size of nvarchar is 255 (MSSQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

Why is the default size of `nvarchar` is 255 (`MSSQL Server`)?
I mean why not 256?

And should I use `nvarchar(63)` instead of `nvarchar(64)` and so on ... 127 instead 128?

I tried to Google this question and I didn't find any comprehensive answer.

---

Edited:

About default size: It is just my assumption. Hibernate and EclipseLink (java persistence frameworks) convert String to nvarchar(255) so I thought this is so kind of standard.

Comment: The default size is *NOT* 255 on SQL Server.   Where did you get that information?

Comment: It is just my assumption. Hibernate and EclipseLink (java persistence frameworks) convert String to nvarchar(255) so I thought this is so kind of standard.

Comment: Then Hibernate and EclipseLink have a default length, but not SQL Server. And I think that default length is based on some urban legend that there using 255 as the length makes a difference

Comment: In regards to SQL Server read @aaron-bertrand blog [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) is quite clear:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

ALWAYS use a length specification for these variables.

As for your second question.  The types `varchar` and `nvarchar` encode the length of the value for each value.  I am not sure if SQL Server uses 1 byte for lengths up to 255 and then 2 bytes for lengths up to 4000/8000.  The `max` does use 4-bytes.  (And all of them can now spill over to additional pages.) In general, for variable character strings, you should use a value that is amply large for whatever you want to include, so you don't have to change the length using `alter table`.  Only the necessary storage for a particular value is used, so a slightly longer declaration does not affect performance.

Note that for `char` and `nchar`, you want the shortest possible length because the column will actually occupy that storage space.